# How to implement gwt:onLoadErrorFn in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to implement onLoadErrorFn in my host file when loading gwt application. I'm not certain how it should be done. http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/gwt/9781933988290/quick-reference/app02lev1sec3

Parts of my host file:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="gwt:onLoadErrorFn" content="onGwtModuleLoadError"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="..../>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="..../>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function onGwtModuleLoadError(message) {
             alert("onGwtModuleLoadError(" + message + ")");
          }
      </script>
```

When I run the host page I get the error: Bad handler for "onGwtModuleLoadError" for "gwt:onLoadErrorFn"

Comment: I'm fairly sure the error is originating from the `onGwtModuleLoadError()` since the reference clearly states that the method should take one (message) parameter. Have you tried omitting the no-args method?

Comment: @per_jansson there's no overloading in JS! A function can be called with any number of arguments; formal parameters past the number of given arguments are filled with `undefined`, and conversely arguments past the number of formal parameters are accessible through the `arguments` variable.

Comment: Yes, I did try to only have one function that takes a message and got the same error (bad handler). I've updated the code example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. I updated the code example since I had two included javascripts declared before my function. When I shuffled around it worked:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="gwt:onLoadErrorFn" content="onGwtModuleLoadError"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function onGwtModuleLoadError(message) {
         alert("onGwtModuleLoadError(" + message + ")");
      }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="..../>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="..../>
```

Comment: You may also want to change: `<script type="text/javascript" src="..../>` to: `<script type="text/javascript" src="....></script>`